Is there a database of interesting groups and graphs?
I'm starting research on graph theory, focusing on properties related to their automorphism groups. I'm quite fond of examples, and I thought a fun way to study would be something like 'Every day a group' or 'Every day a graph' - constructing an interesting group or an interesting graph and proving some basic properties of them. So, I'm looking for references (books, websites, and etc) where I could find good examples. I'm not looking for any exhautive database of all possible groups or graphs - more like examples that are interesting for one reason or another, like being known counterexamples, or the only ones with a certain property, or just being pretty in some way (if the references has images, that'd be cool). They could be finite or infinite, but my advisor works mostly with infinite graphs, so finding a good reference of infinite graphs would be pretty good.
Right now, for groups, my main reference of examples is the book by Robert Wilson, The Finite Simple Groups.

I'd really like a graph database, but that you can query it with a drawing, i.e. detexify style

Perhaps you may like Wolfram Mathematica GraphData[]. A video about it is at https://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/video.php?c=104&ob=title&o=ASC&v=1328

https://houseofgraphs.org/ is also an interesting database. (Actually, it's added a "draw a graph to search" feature recently.)

There is the Stanford Large Network Dataset Collection.
